# Set up a marketplace tips / donations system

Tags: stripe-payments, payment

I have a site with a lot of suppliers and end users. I would like the end users to be able to give tips to suppliers while taking a commission in between.

What's the easiest way to set this up? My plan initially was to code a custom stripe integration into my node.js backend. But there might be an easier way? Maybe someone has written a lot of what's needed already.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[Stripe Connect](https://stripe.com/docs/connect) is Stripe's API that lets you process payments on behalf of third-parties, and optionally take a cut out of the transaction.

There's a lot of things to consider depending on your exact use case so I recommend you take some time to browse the documentation. [This article](https://support.stripe.com/questions/considerations-for-platforms-using-connect) is also a good resource.